# KMP compose android prevent controller ui interaction and listen to joystick and key events everywhere in app

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a kmp application using compose for android mainly.
I want to disable controller interaction with ui for the application
and listen to joystick and key events anywhere in the application.

currently when I have a dialog open or something of the sort the controller interacts with it and doesn't send joystick events to activity dispatch motion and key event and I dont know how to work around it.

I tried dispatch key and motion event but it still interacts with dialogs,
I tried touch event but it still interacts.
when I said try I mean as returned true for these.
I also tried composable key modifier and pointerinterop but had no success.
The thing is that it not only blocks the ui but the events also stops calling when there is something like a dialog showing